# ComboBox in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, combobox, textbox, drop-down-menu

I can do DropDownList

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="YearList" runat="server" oninit="YearList_Init1" />
```

but I can't edit text manually there.

I can do Text box with Ajax DropDown extender but I can't select->Insert to textbox there. Only display :S

**Question : how to create DropDownList which I can edit manually ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a ComboBox.

There is the official [ASP.Net AJAX ComboBox](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[AutoComplete using jquery](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete)**

Also see **[jQuery AutoComplete](http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-autocomplete.html)**